# CSV file locked for editing after join

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, csv

I have created a table join between a vector shapefile and a CSV file using pyQgs.

Now I want to edit the CSV file (not from inside QGIS), but when I double click on the CSV file, it says that the file is locked for editing by another process (which means by QGIS).

Is there any way I can edit the CSV file without losing QGIS or removing the CSV file from my QGIS project?

Once I edit the CSV, I just want to reload the edited file into QGIS project by another Python script.  I just do not want to close QGIS at any point.

Comment: Could you edit your csv file using a text editor such as Notepad?

Comment: did you check the 'watch file' option when you imported the csv (it's off by default in 2.10, but on by default in earlier versions if I remember correctly)

Comment: @Joseph I just tried that and was able to edit it. Thanx for that .
But i plan to edit this csv using java code , so will i be able to edit or a write error is likely to occur?

Comment: @StevenKay Actually i imported this csv using python code , where i did not explicitly mention anything about the watch file option . Hence the default  must have been applied . I am using QGIS 2.10

Comment: @jps - I never used Java before so can't help you there, apologies. Only one way to find out, test it :)